# Assign different types of variable to one type

Tags: c#, type-conversion

As a **very** simplified and stupid example of what I'm dealing with, suppose I had the following class with a simple static `int` property:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static int MyVar { get; set; }
}
```

So, if I wanted to set that property via code, it would be easy enough with something such as:

```
MyClass.MyVar = 2;
```

But, how could I take care of (again, to simplify the example) passing in a `string` and have it converted to an `int`?

The only way I could think of doing it is to create a helper method such as:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static int MyVar { get; private set; }
    public static void SetMyVar(string sMyVar)
    {
        MyVar = int.Parse(sMyVar);
    }
}
```

And then in code run:

```
MyClass.SetMyVar("2");
```

I would love to know if there was a better way to accomplish this than having to add in that extra method.

Comment: Please explain why you need this and why you're asking this. You can create implicit or explicit conversions for example (which I assume you have found, but which is not present in your question), but it sounds like you have a lot of different types that you wish to convert to (for example) `int`. Perhaps there's a better approach altogether.

Comment: Personally I think it's better *with* it being obvious what's going on. If you were able to simply assign a `string` expression to an `int` property, I'd consider that confusing.

Comment: @DangerZone you can't have multiple `get` taking different types...

Comment: In my current class, I have multiple properties that are of the type of a custom class I've written (call it `NewClass`, say) that takes a `List(x)` in its constructor. So I need to pass in the `List(x)` and then end up with the property of type `NewClass`. Does that make sense?

Comment: both `int` and `string` are `IConvertible` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: John Bustos - side note: settable static property is just bad example to start with... Maybe you should update your sample to be avoid static and additionally show syntax you'd like to see (even if it is invalid).

Comment: @Jodrell, like I said, that's a simple and stupid example - Please see my above comment explaining a bit more....

Comment: You could make a custom setter method, a one that accepts string as input.. but that is just about the solution you proposed..

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, thanks for the comment, but that's confusing to me in and of itself - If I have a variable that I know will be constant throughout all instances of my object, doesn't it make sense to make it static and only set it once? Please understand, I am a MAJOR novice here so truly just asking because I don't know / understand better. THANKS!!

Comment: _"In my current class [...] Does that make sense?"_ - not really :P Can you update your question with a more concrete example? Can you show what code you have to type and why you don't want that?

Comment: John, sorry but it is still unclear what you are trying to do.  Are you saying your NewClass has a number of properties of different types, and you need to pass a List(x) (all the same type) that has a list of the values that go into those properties?

Comment: @JohnBustos my concern was about discussion steering away from what you want to "why unrelated feature shown in the sample should not be used" (in this case - `static` is generally frowned upon and *could* have steered discussion toward that). Luckily for this post it looks like you still have not figured out what you want (or at least did not put in the post) and as result comments are more on-topic of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: To all of you, **THANK YOU** - Based upon this feedback, I took the conversion out of the class itself and ended up passing in the correct variable type so this question is moot... Truly, thank you!!

Comment: On topic: when figuring out what you want try to keep in mind that most people expect that after setting property `foo.Prop1 = x;` following will be true `x == foo.Prop1` which is generally hard to achieve with magical conversions.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - what John was trying to do was not "magical conversions".  It seems to me he was trying to see if there is a way to do **type abstraction** at this level.  C# is too strongly typed for that, so there isn't.  Be careful that your language contributes to a positive discussion environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you definitely shouldn't do this because it's confusing to read, you *could* create the property this way

```
class MyClass
{
    private static int _property = 0;

    public static object Property
    {
        get
        {
            return _property;
        }
        set
        {
            _property = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
    }
}
```

You would have to cast this to an int whenever you wanted to use it as an integer but this is best I could think of.

Comment: Ahem! - this is what I had in my answer, almost 20 minutes before you added this.

Comment: @Anon316 Ahem! Actually it isn't. My version uses `public static object` which would allow you to pass a string in as a value. in your example you're using `public static int` which would not allow a string passed in.

Comment: iismathwizard, given the insanity of my question, it truly seems your answer was the most useful / on-point... Thank you!!!

Comment: I so want to down-vote this, despite you saying - quite rightly - that it shouldn't be done. It's been accepted as the "right" answer by @JohnBustos, which makes me really sad. I'll resist downvoting, but really wish you hadn't posted it as an answer as some poor developer's eyes will be made to bleed when they encounter this in real code some time in the future.

Comment: It's just my internet points. Idc. Op had a question, I gave warning and a solution

Answer (score 0):

is this what you were trying to do?

```
    class newclass
    {
        private static int MyVarValue = 0;
        public static int MyVar
        {
            get;
            set
            {
                MyVarValue = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

This would not compile because the value that a property gets set to **has to** be of the same type as the property itself.  But if you are taking a list of objects in a constructor and assigning them to the properties, there you can do something like this...

```
    class newclass
    {
        private static int MyVarValue = 0;
        public newclass(List<object> startingList)
        {
            MyVarValue = Convert.ToInt32(startingList[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `value` is an `int` in this code, so why convert it to an `int`?

Comment: Sorry, but the setter automatically assumes the type of the value passed is the same as the type of the value being set - It won't help.

Comment: I think what he is trying to do is to take a constructor for newclass that takes in a list of objects, and assigns the values of the properties of newclass to the elements of that list.  I will change the code to make this answer more clear.

Comment: @JohnBustos - I know.  But we were trying to figure out what he is trying to do, and asking him to provide even code that would not compile to see if we could understand him.  I know this would not compile, but it was meant to clarify his question and I don't know how to put code in a comment.

Comment: Anon, thanks for the update, but it seems this still has the issue of the initialization occurring at the instance-level, not the static level, no??

Comment: @JohnBustos - Since it is occurring at instantiation, it would not be a true initialization of the static properties, it would just be setting them to the values in the list that got passed to the instance constructor.  But there is nothing wrong with setting static variables when instantiate the class.  You cannot do the reverse (setting instance variables from static method), and you really should have some default values for them anyway, but it is ok to "reset" them at instantiation, right??

Comment: @DavidArno - see my comments to JohnBustos

Comment: I guess so, Anon, it just seems like bad methodology to me in this case, but you're right, it will work and compile... I really thank you for the reply, but I think everyone - you included - were right in saying I just plain shouldn't do things this way to start off with....

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - see JohnBustos question and my comments in answer.

Comment: @JohnBustos - I am not sure about saying categorically this should not be done.  Say you have int, string, double, char and decimal static properties.    Say the values come from a list of strings (maybe user input), and optimization tells you not to take up the time doing the initialization of the static properties until you actually need an instance of the class.  Then I can see ending up with something like what the OP is asking.  If I am correct about what he is asking.

Comment: @Anon316 I see - so you started it as "not an answer"... Clarifying that from the start could be useful. Note that "is this what you were trying to do" on SO essentially means "here is code-only answer and I'm not going to say anything more". Unfortunately there is no way to do what you tried on SO now - clarification comment with nicely looking code...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I started it as "not an answer, but I think this will head clearly towards one".  And there is a way to do what I tried to do.  It's just that other people need to wait a few minutes, and see if a little dialogue with the OP might clarify things, or ask a question of the person doing the answer.  I have appreciated the dialogue with JohnBustos.  It helped me clarify my thoughts and provide what I hope is a better answer.

Comment: @JohnBustos - I just realized you are the OP!  Sorry, lost track of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the compiler's method overload resolution to pick a SetMyValue method depending on the type of the argument.  Inside each SetMyValue method you have a mechanism to convert all of the different input values to the same underlying type.

Doing this is probably a bad idea - but here goes anyway.  It doesn't have quite the semantics that you're asking for but it's close:

```
//A class with multiple 'set' methods that will silently handle
//type conversions
class MyClass{

  private int myValue;

  public int MyValue { { get return this.myValue; } }

  public void SetMyValue(int value){
    this.myValue = value;
  }

  public void SetMyValue(string value){
    this.myValue = Convert.ToInt32(value);
  }
}
```

In statically typed languages, switching types silently in a way that loses information is not a very wise idea.  There are other, dynamically typed languages that let you play fast and loose with types but C# is not one of them.  You have to go out of your way in C# to get dynamic typing.

Doing this is probably a pain in the butt from a maintenance standpoint.  **I would put some more thought into the underlying problem that you're trying to solve that lead to this question.**

Comment: Pete, thanks so much, but what I asked (I ended up changing my code to no longer really ask it, though) was how to avoid using the `SetMyValue` method - Otherwise, what I stated in my question would have worked as-is too....